# How do I dot into a JSON object returned from TranslateService with dashes in it?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using TranslateService (@ngx-translate/core) to get some strings in the current language like this:

```
this.translate
  .get(['hotline-card.email-subject', 'hotline-card.email-body'])
  .subscribe((strings) => {
    console.log('strings', strings);
    let subject = strings['hotmail-card.email-subject'];
    console.log('subject', subject);
  });
```

This gives me a strings object that look like this (except in the console the keys are not in quotes):

```
{
    "hotline-card.email-subject": "Some subject",
    "hotline-card.email-body": "Some body"
}
```

But subject is undefined... How do I get the values of the translated strings?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Hyphen is not a valid javascript identifier

Comment: That's **not** JSON.

Comment: That is not a valid JSON. you need to use `"hotline-card.email-subject"` . please check hrere https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: you can only access it using the full key.  jsonObj[' hotline-card.email-body']

Comment: @GangadharGandi Not true. In [RFC 7159, chapter 7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-8) strings are explicitly defined as "any character" - under the provision it is quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Double quotes**. Then you can access since that was an invalid syntax. But the naming convention is weird.

```js
let o = {
    "hotline-card.email-subject": "Some subject",
    "hotline-card.email-body": "Some body"

}

console.log(o['hotline-card.email-subject']);
```

JS by default recommends camel case naming convention. You may use this structure as my suggestion.

```js
let  o = {
  "hotlineCard": {
    "email": {
      "subject": "Some subject",
      "body": "Some body"
    }
  }
}

console.log(o.hotlineCard.email.subject)
```

Comment: As a suggestion to improve your answer: maybe you can show a proper structure as well?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Added my suggestion.